# Load and subscribe on extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onesignal

I'm starting to create a simple chrome extension and one of the features I need is a notification system, so I'm using `onesignal`, in my script. I wish the user when installing the chrome extension to subscribe automaticlly, but it is not loading the object of `onesignal` which I can't figure out why. I'm saying this because no subscriptions is showing up after I install it.

My code:
manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My title",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "some description",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js","OneSignal.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "my extension"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "gcm",
    "notifications",
    "storage",
    "identity"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
OneSignal.init({appId: "dasdasd-b228-437d-bb8f-43asdasdb3", googleProjectNumber: "99999999"});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you're loading background.js before loading onesignal. Try re-ordering your scripts array

Comment: Thanks a loit, your right, was strange because it wouldnt give me any error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the scripts order:

Solution:

```
...
background": {
    "scripts": [
      "OneSignal.js","background.js"
    ],
..
```